# Вопрос по форматированному выводу в awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, git-bash

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с логикой `printf` в awk. Например, a делаю форматированный вывод для -1 через `%u`.

```bsh
$ gawk --bignum 'BEGIN {printf "%u\n", -1}'
> 18446744073709551615
```

Результат - это переход через интервал (0; 2^64 - 1). Я делаю вывод, что целые значения для unsigned определены на этом интервале. Соответственно, для

```bsh
$ gawk --bignum 'BEGIN {printf "%u\n", -9223372036854775808}'
> 9223372036854775808
```

всё работает. Но только перешагиваем через 2^63, всё "ломается"

```bsh
$ gawk --bignum 'BEGIN {printf "%u\n", -9223372036854775809}'
> -9.22337e+18
```

т.е. `%u` перестаёт работать, выводится само число. Хотя, вроде, значение должно попадать в интервал `(0; 2^64 - 1)`. Почему так происходит?

Comment: может питон какой-нибудь задействовать...

Comment: Питон? Вопрос не о том, как в принципе сделать. Вопрос именно про gawk.

Comment: @Victor  Я одного не пойму... Зачем **отрицательное** число выводить по формату %u ?! Очевидно же, что ничего хорошего из этого не получится. Может быть Вы просто скажете, что Вам нужно сделать на самом деле?

Comment: В данный момент я просто изучаю bash и awk. Здесь столкнулся с ситуацией, которую не могу понять. Предполагаю, что вопрос связан с типами, и к форматированию относится только косвенно, но может проявляться и в других случаях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации [описаны пределы](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computer-Arithmetic.html), конкретно для диапазона 64-битного знакового:

```
64-bit signed integer   -9,223,372,036,854,775,808  9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

(не забываем, что минус тоже занимает место — один бит), а также [комментарий к `%u`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html):

```
Print an unsigned decimal integer.
(This format is of marginal use, because all numbers in awk are floating point; it is provided primarily for compatibility with C.)
```

Там же чуть ниже:

```
NOTE: When using the integer format-control letters for values
that are outside the range of the widest C integer type, gawk switches to
the ‘%g’ format specifier.
```

Для поддержки больших чисел `awk` должен быть собран [с поддержкой GMP](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arbitrary-Precision-Integers.html).

Поводя итоги, документация описывает необходимые условия для работы с большими числами, хотя ответ на ваш вопрос не лежит на поверхности, а скорее является особенностью имплементации.